# Opencv read function not able to read some mp4 videos but can read other mp4 videos

Tags: python, opencv

I have two different MP4 videos, I can read one of them through cv2.read but can't read the other video.

I have tried storing both the videos at same location.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Capture video from file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('GP190763.MP4')
print(cap.get(3))
print(cap.isOpened())
while True:

  ret, frame = cap.read()
  print(frame)
  print(ret)
  if ret == True:

      gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

      #cv2.imshow('frame',gray)


      if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

  else:
      break

cap.release()
```

"ret" variable is false for one of the videos and True for the other video. 
I have double checked that both videos are MP4 videos. 
Any other properties of video I should be comparing ?

Comment: what is the output of `print(cap.isOpened())` for both cases?

Comment: output of  `print(cap.isOpened())` is True
output of `print(frame)` is None
output of `print(ret)` is False

Comment: Test the codec of the videos. For example, open the videos in VLC and check if you can play the video, if you can see the end time of the video, etc. the properties page may not show much, but playing the video may help

Comment: I have played the video in VLC player and I do see the end time.

Comment: Try adding a `sleep()` function before the while loop. maybe it's taking some time to open the video? This is tough to debug..